# The locked post description is either wrong or misleading

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-posts

So I came across [this locked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38635/8718143) today, and I noticed some stuff in the accepted answer that was out of date. The lock on the question gives the following description:

> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

Because of this, I thought that I would be able to edit the accepted answer. However, when I clicked the "edit" link on the post, it came up with an error saying "Question is locked".

Confused, I went looking for more on the topic. [The Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/376967) about locked questions states the following:

> A question or answer which is *locked* can no longer accept:
>
> - edits
> - up-votes, down-votes
> - comments, comment up-votes
> - new answers *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*
> - close votes, reopen votes *<sup>(questions only)</sup>*

I was able to post a comment on the accepted answer, which confused me until I realised that the comment disabling only applies on the locked post itself (in this case the question). However, there is nothing stated anywhere about not being able to edit a locked question.

So, in light of this confusion (it's actively *encouraged* in the locked post description that I should be able to edit the answers, but I can't), should this be changed?

Also, why can't I edit locked posts if the site says I can? Is there a rep minimum that's not stated?

P.S. If it's straight up not allowed, why was this decision made? This *seems* to me like a case where originally locked posts were meant to be able to be edited, but a switch was flipped somewhere which disallowed this. But surely we as a community are meant to keep content up to date?

---

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot of what comes up when I click "edit" on the accepted answer.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue, as I just edited the answer you mention. Are you certain you cannot edit that answer and did not click edit on the question on accident?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that it has something to do with reputation.  Both Travis and I are above 2K reputation, and you're well below it.  Users with 2K rep can edit anything anywhere.  [This FAQ entry seems to contradict my theory, though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/175248)

Comment: I believe you require *full edit* privs. That answer has been converted to a community wiki now though - that should make updating the post available to more people.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm certain. I added a screenshot to show what this looks like for me

Comment: @JonClements that makes sense. Should the locked description be updated to reflect this distinction? Thank you for making it a community wiki :)

Comment: Maybe the error message could be a bit more descriptive... There's very few of these kinds of posts though...

Comment: Did you read the paragraph below your quote from the MSE FAQ?

Comment: I agree, we should prevent commenting on answers to a locked question as well.

Comment: @gparyani Well, that's awkward... I was skimming, and I assumed the relevant information would be in the bullet pointed list...

Comment: I managed to reproduce it with my 1 reputation sock puppet, but not with my main account. Also, when I'm logged out, there is no edit link at all.