# Update the locked question description

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, error-message, locked-posts

**Note:** this question is a follow up to [one I posted previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363354/8718143).

---

## Identified Problem

On a locked question, the accompanying text is as follows:

> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

This is accurate for users with full editing privileges, however users without enough reputation will encounter the following error when they try to edit an answer on the locked question:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

This is confusing and irritating, and it took a meta post for me to sort out what was happening.

---

## Proposed Solution

In order to fix this problem, we should make a change to the text which accompanies the lock. Rather than the text I've quoted above, we should have something like:

> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here.*
>
> You need at least 2,000 reputation to edit non community wiki answers on this question.

As well as this, I think the error message which pops up when a <2,000 rep user tries to edit an answer needs to be improved as well, to better reflect why the action can't be performed. Something like:

> This action requires 2,000 reputation.

This should hopefully clear up any confusion users have about locked posts, negating the need for lengthy confused posts like the one I made earlier.

Comment: http://www.givegoodux.com/the-power-of-progressive-disclosure/

Comment: The fact that I as a moderator was not aware that users without full editing privileges could not suggest edits to non-wiki answers to wiki-locked questions says a lot.

Comment: Look at that, another reason why locks in general are a bad idea to keep indefinitely.

Comment: @Braiam I would support you if you make a proposal to prevent indefinite locks; likely restricting the locks to, maybe, 1 year max,  renewable if activity requires it.

Comment: Supporting Hans Passant: we may not need to disclose all the mechanisms in the accompanying text. But **improving the error message is a must**.